# Create layout programmatically and set ClickListener(android)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listener

I need create one algorithm. I have method its create layout, in this layout i need appoint clickListener in this layout. I can not think of anything, please help me do this.

this method create layout

```
public LinearLayout createLinearLayout(int i) {
    LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
    linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    paramsLayout.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);
    linLayout.setLayoutParams(paramsLayout);
    linLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#26000000"));

    linLayout.setId(i);

    return linLayout;
}
```

i dont know how currectly do listener in layout, i do this, but its not work

```
View.OnClickListener myOnlyhandler = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()) {
            case 0:
                Log.e("0", "0");
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.e("1", "1");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You think of this? : linLayout.setOnCLickListener(myOnlyhandler);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:
`linLayout.setOnClickListener(myOnlyHandler)`

I think you also have to set `linLayout.setClickable(true)`

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to set your click listener to your layout `linLayout.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);`

```
public LinearLayout createLinearLayout(int i) {
        LinearLayout linLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        linLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        paramsLayout.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 10);
        linLayout.setLayoutParams(paramsLayout);
        linLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#26000000"));

        linLayout.setOnClickListener(myOnlyhandler);

        linLayout.setId(i);
        return linLayout;
    }
```